# Can you control what a bitwise right shift will fill in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

As far as I know when you use a left shift bitwise operator in C it's guaranteed that the vacant bits will be filled with 0s. However, I've read that the right shift is implementation-dependent, meaning in some machines the vacant bits will be filled with 0s, in others they will be filled with 1s.

I am using the right shift in a program, and indeed my machine is filling the vacant bits with 1s. Problem is I would need it to fill with 0s instead.

Is there a way to force 0s to be used on right shifts?

One solution would be, after the right shift is applied, to create a mask like 011111111 and then apply a bitwise AND, which will change the leftmost 1 that was inserted to a 0.

But this is cumbersome and wastes time. If there was a way to tell my machine to fill right shifts with 1s it would be much easier.

Thanks

Comment: What platform / OS / compiler are you using?

Comment: @Stephen Gross, GCC on Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Also see [Sign extending from a constant bit-width](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#FixedSignExtend)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Cast the number to `unsigned` and then shift.  That will force a 0-fill.

Comment: Sweet. That's exactly what I needed. Do you know the explanation for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DanielS: For signed integers one can argue that `>>` should preserve the sign and therefore should sign extend.  For unsigned integers, it makes no sense to sign extend at all.

Comment: @DanielS: I thought you were trying to force it to fill with 1s.

Answer (score 27):

No, you can't.

Shifts on unsigned types are well defined (as long as the right operand is in non-negative and   less than the width of the left operand), and they always zero-fill.

Shifts (or any bitwise operations) on signed types are generally not a good idea.  If the left operand is negative then `<<` has undefined behavior, and `>>` yields an implementation-defined result (meaning that the compiler has to document what it does, but there's no way for you to control it).  For non-negative values of a signed type, the result is what you'd expect -- as long as it doesn't overflow (if it overflows, the behavior is undefined).

Here's what the [C99 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says (section 6.5.7):

> The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type
> of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value of
> the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width
> of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of **E1** << **E2** is **E1** left-shifted **E2** bit
> positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If **E1** has an unsigned
> type, the value of the result is **E1** × 2<sup>**E2**</sup>, reduced modulo one more
> than the maximum value representable in the result type. If **E1** has a
> signed type and nonnegative value, and **E1** × 2<sup>**E2**</sup> is representable in
> the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.
>
> The result of **E1** >> **E2** is **E1** right-shifted **E2** bit positions. If **E1** has
> an unsigned type or if **E1** has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
> the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of **E1** /
> 2<sup>**E2**</sup>. If **E1** has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting
> value is implementation-defined.

Coming back to this answer 11+ years later, an implementation certainly *could* offer an option to control the behavior of implementation-defined shifts. I don't know of any that do so.

I cited the C99 standard. I don't believe there have been any relevant changes in later editions.

Comment: You said ">> yields an implementation-defined result" and the A.I. cited this. In the 2023 Korean regional government 9th hiring test, it asked what the result will be if you right-shift a signed binary `10110101` by 2 bits in C. It had both `(1) 00101101` and `(4) 11101101` in the selectable options, and only (4) was the correct answer. It did not specify the name of the C compiler, hardware, or the OS. So, if what you are saying is correct, shouldn't both (1) and (4) be the correct answers? It's a very competitive test where one point difference can determine whether you get hired or not.

Comment: @DamnVegetables I believe the test is wrong; (1) is the only correct answer -- though I'd have to see the exact wording to be sure. (I don't speak Korean, so that might not do me much good.) The standard states that the integer promotions are performed on each of the operands, so binary `10110101` (decimal `181`, hex `0xb5`) is promoted to `int`. `int` is at least 16 bits (`INT_MAX >= 32767), so that leading `1` is *not* a sign bit. `181 >> 2` is `45` in decimal, `0x2d` in hex, `101101` in binary.

Comment: Perhaps `10110101` was meant to be an 8-bit signed integer, but C has no arithmetic or bitwise operations on integers narrower than `int` and `unsigned int`. Note that C doesn't have binary integer constants, though the upcoming C23 standard adds them, so you could write `0b10110101` -- which is of type `int`. You can talk about shifts on 8-bit numbers, but not in C, which has no such operations.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different right shift operations: arithmetic, and logical.

The logical shift is used with unsigned numbers in C. It always fills in the high bits with zeroes. This is what you need.

The arithmetic shift is used with signed numbers, because it preserves the sign of the number being shifted. If the number is positive, the most significant bit will be 0, and it will fill with 0s. If the number is negative, the most significant bit will be 1, so it will fill with 1s.

Note that in Java, these actually use different operators: `>>` for arithmetic, `>>>` for logical. This is needed because Java has no unsigned type.