# php extension >> bug

Tags: php, c, php-extension

To write a PHP extension, I use `>>` in it but unexpectedly it goes wrong.

**code:**

```
printf("%08x ", (W[16]));
printf("%08x ", (W[16]) >> 17);
printf("%08x ", 2425545216 >> 17);
```

**result:**

```
9092e200 40c04849 00004849
```

**note:**

`W[16]=0x9092e200 = 2425545216`, In c ,the code works right. But in php extension ,`>>` dosen't padding 0 to the left.

**php_version:** PHP: 7.1.7
thank you for your help.

Comment: Do not edit your question to include an answer. Upvote any answers you found helpful, and mark accepted the one answer that answered your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, the result of bitwise right shift operation on a signed integer is implementation-defined. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422424/can-you-control-what-a-bitwise-right-shift-will-fill-in-c), for instance.

The value `0x9092e200` can be interpreted as unsigned integer `2425545216` as well as signed integer `-1869422080`. For example, the following code outputs `-1869422080 2425545216`:

```
int x = 0x9092e200;
printf("%d %d",  x, (unsigned)x);
```

So if you want to fill the vacant bits with zeroes, cast `W[16]` to unsigned, e.g.:

```
printf("%08x ",  ((unsigned int)W[16]) >> 17);
```